# Google Tag Manager dataLayer overwrites pervious data

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I am trying to implement a system on a webshop, that can collect to google analytics, weather or not a user is a new visitor, or a returning visitor - This is based upon weather or not the user gets created upon checkout or if the user is already logged in.

I've gotten the data to send to google analytics through a custom dimension, created in GTM.

However my problem lies in, that i can get the analytics page to display "New Visitor" when a user is initially created. But if the user goes ahead and makes a new order right after the first order, the previous data is overwritten, and both orders becomes "Returning Visitor" in google analytics.

[image]

How do i get each order to stay as it is in google analytics ?

Here is the code i've used to push my data.

```
var dataToPush = {
    'event': 'transactionEvent',
    'transactionId': '112256',
    'transactionAffiliation': 'CompanyName',
    'transactionTotal': 250.00;,
    'transactionTax': 0,
    'transactionShipping': 0,
    'CustomReturningVisitor' : 'Old Visitor',
    'transactionProducts': []
}

dataLayer.push(dataToPush);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your custom dimension has a scope of "session" or "user", meaning that it can only have one single value per session lifetime or even user lifetime, with new values overwriting old values.

Make sure to set the scope of your custom dimension to "Hit" to record whether or not a customer is new or returning for every pageview or transaction (or event etc.) separately.

See the [custom dimension reference on scope](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828#scope).

Comment: So i've tried to change the scope from "session" to "hit", and ran the test again, but the problem still persists. 
Does it take a while before the scope is actually updated  ?

Comment: I don't really know to be honest. It's also not very clear from the documentation what the consequences of chagning the scope are regarding previous data. You could try setting up a completely new custom dimension to make sure the concept is sound.

Comment: I've tried to set up a new custom dimension, and changed the settings from within Google Tag Manager, but this resulted in, no data being transferred to google analytics, aside from the transaction info

Comment: Look like i've solved the problem - I had a tag that fired along with my transactionEvent. I've now set up the custom dimension to set in directly in the transactionEvent, and made sure that the dimension scope was set to "hit"